# Pagination in WordPress Theme Development

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am building a WordPress theme and I can't add pagination on my 2 pages that I want.
I want to display 4-5 in each page. Everybody says to just remove the already functions ( next & previous links ) that WP has and replace them with a simple code. I think that because my theme is from scratch, something is missing. Do I have to create WP_query for the pagination only or something? Here is the link for the website: http://henrileworm.com.34spreview.com/
Any feedback would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Well I have managed to do it locally using MAMP, but it doesn't work on the live url...weird..

Comment: We'll need some code rather than a link to your website! Which simple code have you tried?

Comment: it's alright I fixed it, thanks anyways man

Comment: Answer your own question below then, help the community. :)